# I can't get maven to use properties defined in ~/.m2/settings.xml?

Tags: maven

I am using ~/.m2/settings.xml to store a number of property names used throughout the pom.xml files in my project. If I make the XML invalid (by adding another < for example), maven immediately generates an error, saying that it cannot parse that file. If I leave the XML valid, settings in my appBeans.xml file do not pick of references to properties defined in settings.xml.

Has anyone experienced this problem? I am sort of at my wits end here.

Answer (score 7):

Reflecting properties from Maven configurations works by resources filtering.

Make sure your `settings.xml`, project pom and the target xml file contain correct configurations and reside in correct places.

If I understood correctly, you want to store a property name and value in the settings.xml so the props can be used in your project files. I'll provide a working example:

Define a default profile and properties in `settings.xml`:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <someProp>Value</someProp>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Define resource folder's filtering=true in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Define the property in the xml file (that resides in the `src/main/resources folder`):

```xml
...
<element>${someProp}</element>
...
```

After this you should see the filtered result e.g. in target/classes/appBeans.xml.

Bear in mind that if you're using Eclipse & m2eclipse or similar plugin, it probably won't start using the updated `settings.xml` without restarting Eclipse and it's automatic build will sometimes overwrite your files in the target folder. I'm talking from experience here :)

Answer (score 0):

Maven properties do not get reflected in miscellaneous XML files.

If you add one of these properties to the `<properties/>` element of the specific pom that runs the specific plugin that reads allBeans.xml, does that work? I believe that it will not, and your problem will turn out to be adding to the `<configuration/>` for the plugin to pass the maven properties to it.

If you edit your question to show the plugin that processes appBeans.xml I can make this more specific.